# Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вот мой запрос с использованием курсора. Таблица `Table5` имеет такое же название полей

```
    DECLARE CursorName CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT
        int_z int,
        float_z float,
        date_z datetime,
        string_z nvarchar,
        bool_z bit
    FROM
         Table5 

OPEN CursorName 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName INTO @int_z, @float_z, @date_z, @string_z, @bool_z
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
         PRINT @int_z 
         PRINT ' '
         PRINT @float_z 
         PRINT ' '
         PRINT @date_z 
         PRINT ' '
         PRINT @string_z 
         PRINT ' '
         PRINT @bool_z 
    END

CLOSE CursorName 
DEALLOCATE CursorName
```

И появляется ошибка. Не понимаю что тут не так

```
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 12
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@int_z".
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 15
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@int_z".
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 17
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@float_z".
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 19
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@date_z".
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 21
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@string_z".
Сообщение 137, уровень 15, состояние 2, строка 23
Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@bool_z".
```

Comment: Гм.. а что собственно непонятно-то? вроде даже по-русски пишут.

Comment: Переменные объявляются с помощью declare. В вашем коде нет объявления перечисленных переменных. собственно к сообщению сервера добавить нечего

Comment: А еще не понятно что делает указание типов данных внутри оператора select

Comment: спасибо за ответ, разобрался. Возник вопрос, как все переменные вывести в одну строку через пробел используя PRINT

Comment: *как все переменные вывести в одну строку через пробел используя PRINT* В MS SQL для конкатенации строк (в т.ч. и строк-разделитетей) используется оператор "плюс". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190301(v=sql.105).aspx